# Connect Timeout with Alarm()

Tags: c++, sockets, signals, alarm

Since it seems that I can't find a solution to my original problem, I tried to do a little workaround. I'm simply trying to set a timeout to the `connect()` call of my TCP Socket.

1. I want the `connect()` to be blocking but not until the usual 75 seconds timeout, I want to define my own.
2. I have already tried `select()` which worked for the timeout but I couldn't get a connection (that was my initial problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089128/linux-tcp-connect-with-select-fails-at-testserver) ).

So now I found another way to deal with it: just do a blocking `connect()` call but interrupt it with an alarm like this :

```
    signal(SIGALRM, connect_alarm);
    int secs = 5;
    alarm(secs);
    if (connect(m_Socket, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0 )
    {
        if ( errno == EINTR )
        {
            debug_printf("Timeout");
            m_connectionStatus = STATUS_CLOSED;
            return ERR_TIMEOUT;
        }
        else
        {
            debug_printf("Other Err");
            m_connectionStatus = STATUS_CLOSED;
            return ERR_NET_SOCKET;
        }
    }
```

with

```
static void connect_alarm(int signo)
{
     debug_printf("SignalHandler");
     return;
}
```

This is the solution I found on the Internet in a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933122/socket-timeout-in-c-linux) on stackoverflow. If I use this code the program starts the timer and then goes into the `connect()` call. After the 5 seconds the signal handler is fired (as seen on the console with the `printf()`), but after that the program still remains within the `connect()` function for 75 seconds. Actually every description says that the `connect_alarm()` should interrupt the `connect()` function but it seems it doesn't in my case. Is there any way to get the desired result for my problem?

Comment: i solved my issue after a week.....thnx...

Comment: Did you implement it with sigaction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`signal` is a massively under-specified interface and should be avoided in new code.  On some versions of Linux, I believe it provides "BSD semantics", which means (among other things) that providing `SA_RESTART` by default.

Use [`sigaction`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) instead, do not specify `SA_RESTART`, and you should be good to go.

...

Well, except for the general fragility and unavoidable race conditions, that is.  `connect` will return `EINTR` for *any* signal, not just `SIGALARM`.  More troublesome, if the system happens to be under heavy load, it could take more than 5 seconds between the call to `alarm` and the call to `connect`, in which case you will miss the signal and block in `connect` forever.

Your earlier attempt, using non-blocking sockets with `connect` and `select`, was a much better idea.  I would suggest debugging that.

Comment: sigaction is not working for me on connect(). openSuSe 12 64bit. I have cleared all the SA flags.

Answer (score 1):

While it's relatively easy to setup the [`alarm(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/alarm.2.html) (less the pain of signal handling and system call interruptions), the more efficient way of timing out TCP connection attempts is the [**`non-blocking connect`**](http://books.google.com/books?id=ptSC4LpwGA0C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA448#v=onepage&q&f=false), which also allows you to initiate multiple connections and wait on all of them, handling successes and failures one at a time.